# How to use Reddit API to extract other posts from users that have posted to a particular subreddit?

Tags: reddit

I'm attempting to study the different language usage for a particular subreddit vs posts in other subreddits, but by the same individuals that posted to the original subreddit in question. Is there a way that I can easily do this in reddit API? Or would I have to look at each user in that subreddit dataset and extract their other posts in a brute force manner

I've read a paper that did something similar so it seems like there should be a way to do this easily